# Same category multiple time in different level

Tags: php, magento, categories, product

I want to manage the category like this:

```
Gaming
   |
   ----Key Board and Mice
   ----Headset
Key Board and Mice
   |
   ----Gaming
   ----Mice
```

That means Gaming is present in Level 1 and again in Level 2. So same product can be under gaming category and sub category. How can I do that?

Comment: Do they have different category IDs?

Comment: I do not want different category id